# Android: Is there any way to find out which view was being click

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ListView`with `BaseAdapter` which its items are `LinearLayout`. Inside `LinearLayout`, there're a `TextView` and a `RadioGroup`.

I wrote a `OnItemClickListener` for listview. However, when I clicked the item inside `ListView`. Nothing response!

I want to know how could I find out which view was being Clicked. Is there any method like `Log.setShowClickingView(true)`?

Comment: Please post your code here so we can help you.

Comment: refer [this link](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/). It will guide you in right direction..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to have an event in your Xml that is something like this

```
 android:onClick="myCheckMethod"
```

Remember you need to declare /write this statement for your button and radio button.

Now In your Java file (Class) declare the method and match it with the view and you will know which view was clicked

```
public void myCheckMethod(View v) {
    // does something very interesting

    String Caller = "";
    if (R.id.DI == v.getId()) {
        Caller = "DI";
    } else if (R.id.btnExp == v.getId()) {
        Caller = "Exp";
    } 
    Log.i(Tag,"View Clicked was:"+Caller);
}
```

**Edit** User requested to know how to know the ID

```
getResources().getResourceEntryName(int resid);
```

or

```
getResources().getResourceName(int resid);
```

You'll prefer the first one I guess.

Comment: Thank you so much, This might work. :D
Next problem is now, I need to add onclick to every view in xml file.:(

Comment: Ya pretty much. Only on which you need onClick Event

Comment: I found the bug. I found this bug by setOnClickListener with toast.makeText inside every single view. The real problem is I don't know which view is responsible for the click.
Thank you, again. :D

Comment: @user2511393 sorry.. I couldn't understand completely what you said. Are you asking you still don't have an idea which view was clicked? Is this what you are asking??

Comment: Yes, it is. That's what I asked for.

Answer (score 1):

When using OnItemClickListener, one of the things returned is the position within the listView of the item that was clicked:

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item clicked: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

In the above example, "int position" represents the item that was clicked.  A toast message is displayed with the index of the item that was clicked.

Comment: Actually, I already wrote this. Instead of Toast.makeText, I wrote Log.d("click", "ListView click"); but nothing happenned in LogCat. Thanks for the answer,anyway.:)